# Gulp v4 SFTP file deployment

Tags: deployment, gulp, sftp, gulp-4

Currently I am using "[vinyl-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp)" for deployment. But this is not working with SFTP connections.
What you guys are using for SFTP connection with Gulp 4?

Answer (score 0):

I use [gulp-rsync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rsync), quite possibly, it will suit you too

Comment: `function deployTest(){ 
    return gulp .src('/WIP/assets/test/**') 
    .pipe(rsync({ root: 'sftp.abc.com', hostname: 'abc.com', destination: '/assets/test', username: 'xxx', password: 'xxx', archive: true, silent: false, compress: true, progress: true })); console.log("Deploy Started"); }; `

I tried this. Doesn't work.  Is it possible to provide any example? Thanks.

Comment: ```gulp.task('rsync', function() {
 return gulp.src('app/**')
 .pipe(rsync({
  root: 'app/',
  hostname: 'username@yousite.com',
  destination: 'yousite/public_html/',
  // include: ['*.htaccess'], // Includes files to deploy
  exclude: ['**/Thumbs.db', '**/*.DS_Store'], // Excludes files from deploy
  recursive: true,
  archive: true,
  silent: false,
  compress: true
 }))
});```

Comment: unfortunately, that didnt work. How you mention the password?